# Properly connecting a regex with if statements for inputs

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need to create a form that asks the user to input their first and last name into two different inputs and create a javascript function `regexChecker()` that does the following:

- Pulls in the users information using the DOM from the HTML form
- The first letter of the first name should be capitalized
- The first letter of the last name should be capitalized
- The user must enter more than one character for first and lastname.
- No special characters should be used.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <body>
      <form>
        <h1>Please Enter Your First and Last Name</h1>
        First Name:<input type="text" name="firstname">
        Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastname">
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My JS:

```
function regexChecker(firstname,lastname){
let firstname = /^[A-Z][A-Za-z]+$/
let lastname = /^[A-Z][A-Za-z]+$/
if (regexChecker.test(firstname) && regexChecker.test(lastname)){
    alert("Yay! Your inputs were all correct!");
} else {
    alert("Oh no! Thats an invalid format!");
}
}
```

But when I try it, nothing appears with alert boxes

Comment: `regexChecker` is the name of the function! `firstname&&lastname` is not how you check more than one thing. I am sure there are error messages in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <script src="script7.js"></script>
    <body>
      <form>
        <h1>Please Enter Your First and Last Name</h1>
        First Name:<input id="firstname" type="text">
        Last Name:<input id="lastname" type="text">
        <button id="submit" onclick="regexChecker()">Submit</button> 
      </form>
    </body>
</html>

function regexChecker(){
    let firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    let lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
    let regexChecker = /^[A-Z][A-Za-z]+$/
    if (firstname.match(regexChecker) && lastname.match(regexChecker)){
        alert("Yay! Your inputs were all correct!");
    } else {
        alert("Oh no! Thats an invalid format!");
    }
    }
```

Comment: The answer I got it

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not valid

```
/ regex pattern /.test(string to be checked against)
```

Question asks one or more whereas you regex pattern asks for two or more

```
^[A-Z][A-Za-z]*$
```

- [A-Z] - Match A to Z any character one time
- [A-Za-z] - Match A to Z  or a to z any character one or more time

You need to change `+` quantifier to `*` which means `match zero or more time`

---

```js
function regexChecker(firstname,lastname){
  let firstName = prompt('Enter your first name')
  let lastName = prompt('Enter your Last name')
  let regex = /^[A-Z][A-Za-z]*$/
  if (regex.test(firstname) && regex.test(lastName)){
    alert("Yay! Your inputs were all correct!");
  } else {
    alert("Oh no! Thats an invalid format!");
  }
}

regexChecker()
```

Comment: The let regex isnt defined for me

Comment: What ? i just changed the name of regex pattern to `regex` whereas you had same regex with two variable name `firstName` and `lastName`

Comment: I see, my only issue is the alerts will not display when I submit them